# LDAP user not present in the desired group

Tags: linux, rhel, nfs, openldap

We have LDAP and NFS setup in the lab. The lab has 16 machines and a server. All the LDAP users home directory is present in the server. Whenever, the LDAP user logs in from any of the 16 machines, his home is presented from the server in the client machine through the NFS automounting.

In all the client machines, we have installed virtualbox and created a group as **vboxusers** which has all the LDAP users. So, whenever the LDAP user logs in any of the client machine and runs virtual box, he will be able to use the Virtual Box.

However, in one of the machine after the fresh installation of RHEL and VirtualBox, when I run the VirtualBox as the LDAP user, I am getting the "**guest OS inaccessible**" error. I thought it might be some permission issue and so, I reset the permissions to the **vboxusers** in that machine.

However, on further investigation, we found out that the LDAP users are actually not assigned to the group "**vboxusers**" but rather to some other group. How can this be possible, as I copied the LDAP and NFS configuration files from the working machines in the lab and used the same files in the newly installed machine?

**EDIT:**

*ldap.conf contents*

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example, dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT  12
#TIMELIMIT  15
#DEREF      never
URI ldap://192.168.1.10/
BASE dc=xxx,dc=xxx
#TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

Comment: can you please post the content of your config files and ldifs? Which ldap distribution do you use?

Comment: LDAP Version:

ldapsearch: @(#) $OpenLDAP: ldapsearch 2.3.43 (Jun 26 2012 06:37:13) $
        mockbuild@hs20-bc2-4.build.redhat.com:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.3.43/openldap-2.3.43/build-clients/clients/tools
        (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20343)

Comment: I have updated the answer with the contents of ldap.conf file..

Comment: Means at the end you want to Replicate LDAP Server in your Test Lab, am I correct ?

Comment: you want same LDAP Setup in your LAB ?

Comment: yeah. I need the same LDAP setup. The LDAP users are strangely assigned to some other group and if I assign permissions to that group only, the LDAP users are able to access the Virtual Box.

Comment: @Ramesh Let me know, if have any doubts and facing any issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the incorrect group ID being assigned. When the system was installed freshly, the system arbitrarily assigned the group ID 501 to another group.

In all the remaining machines of the lab, we had the group ID 501 assigned to **vboxusers**. That was the reason, the LDAP users were unable to access the VirtualBox in that particular machine.

Answer (score 2):

```
How can this be possible, as I copied the LDAP and NFS configuration
files from the working machines in the lab and used the same files in
the newly installed machine?
```

As I understand you need Same LDAP Server Setup in your LAB, SO we need to export Master LDAP Server database, and then import into New LDAP Server. if I'm correct then you can follow this setup.

## Installation

Note: this Guide based on RHEL5.x/CentOS 5.x

Install OpenLDAP Packages using :

```
yum install openldap
```

Configure server, Edit `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf`, you can configure this settings same as your Master

```
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw          secrete # or you can use encrypted pass using slappasswd
```

copy required file

```
install -o ldap -g ldap /etc/openldap/DB_CONFIG.example /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG
```

On your Master Server, export all details into LDIF file.

```
slapcat -l master.ldif
```

Copy `master.ldif` into New LDAP Server.

Now on your New LDAP Server.

To import the entries specified in file master.ldif into your LDAP data-base give the command:

```
slapadd -l ldif
```

Now Start LDAP Service using :

```
/etc/init.d/ldap start
```

On Client Machine :
Mount NFS on HOME, add required entries in `/etc/fstab`

Then enable LDAP Auth using :

```
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=NEW_LDAPSERVER_IP --
ldapbasedn="dc=example,dc=com" –update
```

## Trouble shooting

By Default ldap Logs is disabled you can Enable LDAP Logs on your LDAP Server using :

Edit  `/etc/syslog.conf`

```
local4.*    /var/log/ldap.log
```

Once restart `syslog` service

```
/etc/init.d/syslog restart
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks a lot for replying back. I am relatively new to system administration. I am not sure if I am following you. I have a LDAP server (centralized server) which authenticates all the users logging to the client using NFS. For this setup, do I have to modify the above mentioned files too? Because, we never encountered such a strange scenario before. Thanks again!

Comment: We can't copy files one server to another server to make thing work, since by default ldap save DIT in burkly database so we need to export and import in new server. So if you have test server then you can test this steps, there is no impact on running ldap server.